# Table spanning two pages

Tags: tables

I have a table whose text is unfortunately a bit longer and does not fit on one page. For this reason I would like to repeat the table on the second page.

I looked at [Tabularx: Break long tables over several pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376790/tabularx-break-long-tables-over-several-pages)
It does not work. The text is still only on one page. How can I make the table repeat itself on the second page?

Also the problem is the hyphenation and spacing. As can be seen here, the text was set with syllables although there was still plenty of space.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column %-----> commented
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{float} %----> added

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]



\begin{landscape}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em} % for the horizontal padding
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption[Name]{Überblick der Phasen des CRISP-DM Prozesses~\cite{PeterChapmanandJanetClintonandRandyKerberandTomKhabazaandThomasP.ReinartzandColinShe.2000}}
        \label{tab:crisp__ueberblick}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
            \hline %-----> added    
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{BusinessUnderstanding}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data Understanding}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data Prepartion}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Modeling}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Evaluation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Deployment}} 
            \\ \hline
            Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
            Hintergrund \newline 
            Unternehmensziele \newline
            Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen \newline
            
            Situation bewerten
            Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
            Erfordernisse
            Annahmen und Beschränkungen
            Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
            Terminologie
            Kosten und Nutzen
            
            Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
            Data-Mining-Ziele
            Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
            
            Projektplan erstellen
            Projektplan
            Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
            & This is another long text what a long text is that \newline And agian an new line
            & sad
            & asd 
            & aa
            & adasd                                    
            
            \\ \hline
            
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

with `xltabular`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[a4paper, left={2.5cm}, right={2cm}, top={3cm}, bottom={3cm}, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column %-----> commented
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{float} %----> added

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]



\begin{landscape}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em} % for the horizontal padding
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
    \begin{table}[H]
        \caption[Name]{Überblick der Phasen des CRISP-DM Prozesses~\cite{PeterChapmanandJanetClintonandRandyKerberandTomKhabazaandThomasP.ReinartzandColinShe.2000}}
        \label{tab:crisp__ueberblick}
        \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
        
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{BusinessUnderstanding}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data Understanding}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data Prepartion}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Modeling}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Evaluation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Deployment}} 
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{6}{c}%
        {\tablename\ \thetable{}: -- continued from previous page} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{BusinessUnderstanding}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data Understanding}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Data Prepartion}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Modeling}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Evaluation}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Deployment}} 
        \endhead
        
        \multicolumn{6}{|r|}{{Continued on next page...}} \\
        \endfoot
        
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        
            Geschäftsziele festlegen \newline
            Hintergrund \newline 
            Unternehmensziele \newline
            Erfolgskriterien für das Unternehmen \newline
            
            Situation bewerten
            Bestandsaufnahme der Ressourcen
            Erfordernisse
            Annahmen und Beschränkungen
            Risiken und Zufälligkeiten
            Terminologie
            Kosten und Nutzen
            
            Bestimmen der Data-Mining-Ziele
            Data-Mining-Ziele
            Data Minig Erfolgskriterien
            
            Projektplan erstellen
            Projektplan
            Erste Bewertung von Tools und Techniken
            & This is another long text what a long text is that \newline And agian an new line
            & sad
            & asd 
            & aa
            & adasd                                    
            
            \\ \hline
            
        \end{xltabular}
    \end{table}
}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with `xltabular`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`?

Comment: @Bernard thank you for your hint. Yes I tried `xltabular` I changed `\begin{tabularx}` to `\begin{xltabular}`. Maybe I did it wrong too.

Comment: You have to use longtable syntax (`endhead, \endfirsthead, &c.`). This being said, you can break a longtable within a cell – only between rows.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the hint! I understand. I have not received my desired output because I am doing something wrong. Please see my edit.

Comment: you didn't take into account that a longtable (or xltabular) cannot break page within a cell, so, in my opinion, you should redesign your table to ensure it will have page breaks between rows.

Comment: So far showed MWE is duplicate to your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646707/create-table-design. if now have problem how to write a long table, I expect that you will start with code from accepted answer on previous question and in tan table body repeat rows as many time as needed that tble protrude bottom of page.

Comment: The main problem is putting longtable or xltabular inside a table environment.  The table environment is not needed for these and will not break across pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of long table using `longtblr` table dafined in `tabularray` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Überblick der Phasen des CRISP-DM Prozesses \cite{PeterChapmanandJanetClintonandRandyKerberandTomKhabazaandThomasP.ReinartzandColinShe.2000}},
  entry =  name,
  label = {tab:crisp__ueberblick},
                ]{
    hlines, vlines,
    colspec = {*{6}{X[j, font=\small]}},
     row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
    rowhead = 1}
Business Understanding
    &   Data Understanding
        &   Data Prepartion
            &   Modeling
                &   Evaluation
                    &   Deployment          \\
\lipsum[66]
    & \lipsum[66]
        &   sad
            &   asd
                &   aa
                    &    adasd      \\
\lipsum[65]
    & \lipsum[66]
        &   sad
            &   asd
                &   aa
                    &    adasd      \\

    \end{longtblr}

\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

From your MWE can be concluded that long text are only in the first two columns. I this is true, than you may consider to make this two columns wider and rest narrower. In `longtblr` this can be simple done by defining columns  widths ratios. For example:

```
    colspec = {*{2}{X[1.2, j, font=\small]}
               *{4}{X[0.9, j, font=\small]} },
```

In this case table looks is :

[image]

**Addednum:**
As mentioned @ barbara beeton in her comment (I I totally agree with her), text in narrow columns is easier to read if it were set ragged right. This is simple to so. Just replace option `j` (justified) by option `l` (left aligned). For example, when in the same time make first two columns even wider,:

```
    colspec = {*{2}{X[2, l, font=\small]}
               *{4}{X[1, l, font=\small]} },
```

[image]

Comment: The text in the first two columns would be easier to read if it were set ragged right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, columns are quite narrow, so you are right, in them adjusted text is more difficult to read. To make ragged right text is simple: option `j`  let replace `l`.  However, there may be more place to make first two column wider and in both cases will reading text in them be easier. I will Add example with ragged right text ASAP